# Disabling Auto Enable Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I use a 13.04 system.
Whenever the system boots up, the Bluetooth button is by default ON..Every time i have to manually disable it.Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Look in your BIOS, see if you can disable that way.

Answer (score 2):

To disable it on boot, you'll need to edit this file:

> sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

And set InitiallyPowered to false

> InitiallyPowered = false

Answer (score 2):

Disable Bluetooth on startup

Source : [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-app-for-13-04/285681#285681)

```
 sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following line before exit 0

```
 rfkill block bluetooth
```

**Save & Exit & Reboot**

Your bluetooth is off on startup but you can enable it from bluetooth icon.